# Switching sidebar when using RTL direction

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar like this:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/m56wW/20/

```
<div class="my_sidebar"> <i style="border: 1px solid blue;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i><br>
.my_sidebar {top: 60px;bottom:0;left:0;position: fixed;width: 30px;height: 100%;background-color: #fa0;border: 1px solid red;opacity: 0.9;z-index:51;}
```

This sidebar is fixed to left side.
It starts from the +60px of the top and width is 30px. This works well for LTR.
But when I change direction to RTL, this sidebar doesn't go to right side. Because of `left:0px`.

Adding a new classs like `.my_sidebar_rtl`, putting `right:0;` inside and including it is an option.

But I wonder whether is it possible to get this behaviour with one `my_sidebar` class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle layouts based on text direction is like this:

**LTR**

```
<html>
```

**RTL**

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

**CSS**

```
.my_sidebar {
    left: 0;
    ...
}

[dir="rtl"] .my_sidebar {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/UbW4W/

Comment: Well, my_sidebar isn't direct child of `html` tag. it exists inside subdivs. Does this work in that case ?

Comment: yes, it will work (the children selector in CSS is >)... let me show you, wait...

Comment: @trante, check the jsfiddle, play adding div's and adding/removing the dir attribute. I've worked with RTL a lot...